# vue.js v-if is still rendering to the page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple component that is on the app html, it is connected to a

```
v-if
```

as I understand from the docs, if v-if is false then the component shouldn't be created yet.

here is the component on the page

```
<post-modal :v-if="postModal" :show.sync="postModal" :post="post">
    <h3 slot="header">Show Post</h3>
</post-modal>
```

and the app code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',
    data: {
        postModal: false,
        postId: null,
        post: null
    }
});
```

as you can see "postModal" is false so the component shouldn't be rendered... but I know it does as in the component "created" method I have an

```
alert('created');
```

what did I do wrong?

thanks!

Comment: I don't think you need the leading ":" for the `v-if` directive.  I think the leading colon is just short-hand notation for the `v-bind` of an HTML attribute.  Try it as `v-if` instead of `:v-if`

Comment: @PatrickSteele that's the cause

Comment: :/ stupidest error ever....

Answer (score 2):

```
<post-modal v-if="postModal" :show="postModal" :post="post">
   <h3 slot="header">Show Post</h3>
</post-modal>
```

[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/e9dsfkrh/)

Comment: please just update the html without the colon so I could mark as answered